# How to sort based on the last two character of a column also with other conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have a table called users. There are thousands of rows and unum is the primary key.
now what i want is to select rows like $unumwc (unum wildcards specified in this variable)
and also sort them based on the last number of another column which is specified by a session variable.
the contents of the other column is in this format: number|number|number
i want it to be sorted based on the last number.

This code is throwing me all rows like $unumwc.

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
WHERE unum LIKE '$unumwc'
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX('$_SESSION['SESS_FILT_C']','|',-1)
```

Even this didnt work. it threw nothing.

```
SELECT '$_SESSION['SESS_FILT_C']', SUBSTRING_INDEX($_SESSION['SESS_FILT_C'],'|',-1)
FROM `users` 
WHERE unum LIKE '$unumwc'";
```

Comment: What kind of a column is unum? If it's an id that is incrementing then you probably don't want to use the `LIKE` clause or else if `$ununwc = 52` then your query will return rows with the id of 5, 2, 52, and 25. This is because the `LIKE` clause selects all where string contains.

Comment: unum contains mixed characters. eg: 1es12098 its of length 10

Comment: Ok... well, make sure you want `LIKE` not equals that way you prevent future potential bugs.

Comment: You're query looks fine syntax wise. What exactly is happening? And more specifically what is your question?

Comment: ya, true. i get it. any ideas to solve my main problem ?

Comment: I'm guessing your `ORDER BY` clause isn't working since PHP needs curly braces to parse array keys in strings, e.g. `{$arr['key']}`.

Comment: Consider normalizing your database. Having a column with format "number|number|number", besides being not normalized, will prevent you from having an index on any of the three values (since MySQL does not support function-based indexes)

Comment: What is your main problem? The query looks fine to me. Except for the fact that if your interpolating variables in your query string you should have `+` signs on either side of your PHP variables.

Comment: the $unumwc is generated based on some filters through a form. now assume that the other column what i'm saying stores points. there are many columns like this.now what i wan't is to get 20 rows sorted in decreasing order according to the last number after the delimiter '|' based on the wildcard. and the other column is a session variable.

Comment: Are you building this query dynamically in PHP?   My guess is that you're passing a string literal of your session variable name instead of the name of a column.    Can you show the code you're using to generate the SQL?

Comment: actually the name of the column is 1,2,3,4,5. through a form the session variable is set to one of the value.

Comment: In your query, only `WHERE` filters the results. You should be getting all rows `WHERE unum LIKE '$unumwc'`. If you require further filtering, add additional expressions to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @pTk You've got to escape this column name with backticks. I don't see any.

Comment: Somebody please cook me a proper query.

Comment: I cracked it I got it.